# How to stop WsgiServer in Linux

Tags: linux, wsgi, cherrypy, wsgiserver

I am a newbee in cherrypy.
I just tried with a sample program of wsgiserver.The program is as follows

```
from cherrypy import wsgiserver

def my_crazy_app(environ, start_response):
  status = '200 OK'
  response_headers = [('Content-type','text/plain')]
  start_response(status, response_headers)
  return ['Hello world!']

server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(
        ('127.0.0.1', 8080), my_crazy_app,
        server_name='localhost')
server.start()
```

I got the output `Hello world` successfully,
but the problem is when i hit `Ctrl-c` on the terminal to stop the server, its not getting stopped. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the wsgiserver itself is not associated to any signal and therefore doesn't respect the SIGINT interruption.
Only the higher level CherryPy engine will provide that. If you can't use it, you probably want to
install a handler using the Python signal module.

Well, something along those lines will do the job:

```
import signal

from cherrypy import wsgiserver 
def my_crazy_app(environ, start_response): 
   status = '200 OK' 
   response_headers = [('Content-type','text/plain')] 
   start_response(status, response_headers) 
   return ['Hello world!'] 

server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer( ('127.0.0.1', 8080), my_crazy_app, server_name='localhost')

def stop_server(*args, **kwargs):
  server.stop()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,  stop_server)

server.start()
```